# Swift avoiding casting with `as`

Tags: swift

I'm fairly new to swift and still trying to get my head around optionals and casting. I've heard/read a lot about avoiding using `!` to force something, but i'm having an issue that i can't seem to get the editor happy with. Check out the following block

```
if let exhibitions = array as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            for exhibition in exhibitions {
                if  let title = exhibition["title"],
                    let audio = exhibition["audio"],
                    let image = exhibition["image"],
                    let description = exhibition["description"] {
                      print(image)
                      let item = ExhibitionItem(title: title as! String, image: image as! [String], audio: audio as! String, description: description as! String)
                      exhibitionsArr.append(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

basically i am feeding this a plist array that contains strings and arrays so i'm using `[[String : AnyObject]]`. My issue is with setting `as! String` for all the data when i add it as an `ExhibitionItem`. Is there a way that i can set the type of object in my `if let` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written is a crash waiting to happen: If there is an item exhibition["title"], but it is not a String, then title as! String later will crash. You should write

```
if let title = exhibition["title"] as? String, 
   let audio = exhibition["audio"] as? String, 
   let image = exhibition["image"] as? [String]
```

etc. and then the as! is not needed anymore.

Comment: ahh perfect thank you man. I was trying stuff like `let audio: String` and stuff. I should look at more examples using `as`